# User role is retrieved from db but it's being ignored by @PreAuthorize with Basic Auth, I get HTTP 403

Tags: spring-security

I'm developing a REST app with Spring security 4.0.3, I send requests using Postman with the Basic Auth. I have my db table users and roles populated. I have overrided the loadUserByUsername which is executed and retrieves properly the user and his role when Basic auth is used.

- I always get a HTTP 403 - Access is denied
- The REST request will always include the Basic Auth
- I tried with several configurations on SecurityConfig.configure() without success
- The annotated method never gets executed

What could I be missing?

These are my files:

AuthService

```
@Service
public class AuthService implements UserDetailsService {
    @Autowired
    private UserDAO userDAO;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        UserVO vo = userDAO.getUserByUsername(new UserVO(username)).get();
        System.out.println("User role: " + vo.getRole()); //The user role is printed successfully
        GrantedAuthority authority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(vo.getRole());
        UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails)new User(vo.getUsername(), vo.getPassword(), Arrays.asList(authority));
        return userDetails;
    }
}
```

AppConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan( basePackages = "com.nemesis" )
@Import({ SecurityConfig.class })
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean 
    public UserService userService() {
        return new UserServiceImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource  dataSource() {
        return new DriverManagerDataSource("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3307/nemesis", "root", "");
    }   

    @Bean
    public UserDAO userDAO() {
        UserDAO userDAO = new UserDAOImpl();
        userDAO.setDataSource(dataSource());
        return userDAO;
    }
}
```

SecurityConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    AuthService authService;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(authService);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .csrf().disable()
        .httpBasic()
        .and().authorizeRequests()
        //.antMatchers("/**").access("hasRole('USER')"); //I tried with this also, no success
        .antMatchers("/**").permitAll();
    }   
}
```

UserController

```
@RestController
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user/{username}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json" )
    public ResponseEntity<UserVO> getUser(@PathVariable String username) throws Exception {
        return userService.getUser(username);

    }
}
```

UserService (This has the annotated method)

```
public interface UserService {
    @PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('ADMIN')")
    ResponseEntity<UserVO> getUser(String username);
}
```

UserServiceImpl

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    UserDAO userDAO;

    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<UserVO> getUser(String username) {
        return new ResponseEntity<UserVO>(userDAO.getUserByUsername(new UserVO(username)).orElseThrow(() -> new CustomUserNotFoundException()), HttpStatus.OK);
    }   
}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
  <display-name>Nemesis</display-name>


  <context-param>
      <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
      <param-value>
         org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
      </param-value>
   </context-param>
   <context-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>com.nemesis.config</param-value>
   </context-param>

    <filter>
       <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
       <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
       <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
       <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>  

   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>
         org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
      </servlet-class>
      <init-param>
         <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
         <param-value>
            org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
         </param-value>
      </init-param>
      <init-param>
         <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
         <param-value>com.nemesis.config</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

The request I send is like this:

[Postman request with basic auth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2DXJ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything was ok, the only problem was that I didn't add the prefix "ROLE_" in the annotation as well in the database, instead of ADMIN I changed to ROLE_ADMIN, that was all.